# GraphQL - Prisma - resolvers using external API

Tags: graphql, resolver, prisma

I'am having this schema:

```
type Invoice {
  id: ID! @unique
  description: String
  charge: Charge
}

type Charge {
  id: ID! @unique
  amount: Float
  dataFromAPI: DataFromAPI
}
type DataFromAPI {
  id: ID! @unique
  status: String
}
```

in the Query Resolver, I have:

```
async function charge(parent, args, ctx, info) {
  chargeData = await ctx.db.query.charge(args, info)
  chargeData.dataFromAPI = await DO_THE_API_CALL_TO_RETRIEVE_DATA()
  return chargeData
}
```

and

```
async function invoice(parent, args, ctx, info) {
  invoiceData = await ctx.db.query.invoice(args, info)
  return invoiceData
}
```

the query:

```
query ChargeQuery {
  charge {
    id
    amount
    dataFromAPI
  }
}
```

will return

```
{
  charge {
    id: '232323'
    amount: 323
    dataFromAPI: 'GREAT! DATA IS FROM API'
  }
}
```

but this query:

```
query InvoiceQuery {
  invoice {
    id
    description
    charge {
      id
      amount
      dataFromAPI
    }
  }
}
```

will return

```
{
  Invoice {
    id: '7723423',
    description:'yeah',
    charge {
      id: '232323'
      amount: 323
      dataFromAPI: null
    }
  }
}
```

`dataFromAPI` is null because I have not called the API in this resolver. 
Where should I call the function `DO_THE_API_CALL_TO_RETRIEVE_DATA()`.
In every resolvers? I guess it is not scalable to do that.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is: 
We should use a resolver on the **field level**.

## schema.graphql

```
type Charge {
  id: ID!
  invoice: Invoice!
  messageErrorPayment: String
  stripeChargeId: String!
  dateErrorPayment: DateTime
  createdAt: DateTime!
  chargeData: ChargeData
}
```

## /resolvers/index.js

```
const { Query } = require('./Query')
const { Mutation } = require('./mutation/Mutation')
const { Charge } = require('./Charge')

module.exports = {
  Query,
  Mutation,
  Charge,
}
```

## charge.js

```
async function chargeData(parent, args, ctx, info) {
  return {
    dataFromAPI: await DO_THE_API_CALL_TO_RETRIEVE_DATA()
  }
}

const Charge = {
  chargeData,
}

module.exports = {
  Charge,
}
```

source: https://www.prisma.io/forum/t/how-to-use-field-resolvers-to-get-aggregates-of-inner-relation-types/2930/2?u=alan345